TikZ: Draw Boxes in Field of Numbers
I want to draw a box around a field of random numbers:

I generated the number field using:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c c c c c c}
5&3&2&0&8&9&9&9&1&2&4 \\  % keep var constant on row
9&3&0&7&6&8&0&1&7&5&3 \\
1&7&5&2&4&9&8&9&7&5&8 \\
1&4&2&0&0&6&3&9&7&3&1 \\
5&2&5&6&1&0&9&2&4&2&9 \\
6&7&4&1&3&{\color{red}8}&5&7&5&9&4 \\
9&9&0&8&5&4&2&0&6&5&0 \\
9&4&1&1&4&3&7&4&6&3&0 \\
2&8&6&7&5&4&9&8&9&7&5 \\
3&0&4&5&5&2&5&3&1&4&7 \\
6&4&4&3&3&2&2&4&4&3&8
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

Does anyone know a solution?
EDIT:
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={text width={width(998888)}, align=right} ]
           {
            5&3&2&0&8&9&9&9&1&2&4 \\  
            9&3&0&7&6&8&0&1&7&5&3 \\
            1&7&5&2&4&9&8&9&7&5&8 \\
            1&4&2&0&0&6&3&9&7&3&1 \\
            5&2&5&6&1&0&9&2&4&2&9 \\
            6&7&4&1&3&{\color{red}8}&5&7&5&9&4 \\
            9&9&0&8&5&4&2&0&6&5&0 \\
            9&4&1&1&4&3&7&4&6&3&0 \\
            2&8&6&7&5&4&9&8&9&7&5 \\
            3&0&4&5&5&2&5&3&1&4&7 \\
            6&4&4&3&3&2&2&4&4&3&8 \\
                   } ;
       \draw (m-4-4.north-|m-4-4.west) rectangle (m-8-8.east|-m-8-8.south);

\end{tikzpicture}

leads to:

This is almost good. However, the left line is a little too far to the left.

Have a look at the nicematrix package

This package includes a way to automatically fill the cell if it is possible here.

Change the text width and the alignment. My solution:
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={text width={width(998)}, align=center} ]
           {
            5&3&2&0&8&9&9&9&1&2&4 \\  
            9&3&0&7&6&8&0&1&7&5&3 \\
            1&7&5&2&4&9&8&9&7&5&8 \\
            1&4&2&0&0&6&3&9&7&3&1 \\
            5&2&5&6&1&0&9&2&4&2&9 \\
            6&7&4&1&3&{\color{red}8}&5&7&5&9&4 \\
            9&9&0&8&5&4&2&0&6&5&0 \\
            9&4&1&1&4&3&7&4&6&3&0 \\
            2&8&6&7&5&4&9&8&9&7&5 \\
            3&0&4&5&5&2&5&3&1&4&7 \\
            6&4&4&3&3&2&2&4&4&3&8 \\
                   } ;
       \draw (m-4-4.north-|m-4-4.west) rectangle (m-8-8.east|-m-8-8.south);

\end{tikzpicture}



With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix and its built-in command \Block.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ c c c c c c c c c c c}
5&3&2&0&8&9&9&9&1&2&4 \\  
9&3&0&7&6&8&0&1&7&5&3 \\
1&7&5&2&4&9&8&9&7&5&8 \\
1&4&2&\Block[draw]{5-5}{}0&0&6&3&9&7&3&1 \\
5&2&5&6&1&0&9&2&4&2&9 \\
6&7&4&1&3&\color{red}8&5&7&5&9&4 \\
9&9&0&8&5&4&2&0&6&5&0 \\
9&4&1&1&4&3&7&4&6&3&0 \\
2&8&6&7&5&4&9&8&9&7&5 \\
3&0&4&5&5&2&5&3&1&4&7 \\
6&4&4&3&3&2&2&4&4&3&8
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}

You need several compilations (because nicematrix uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

